# Can the Hyperledger Fabric Consensus Service be distributed?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, consensus

I've read the [fabric proposal on consensus architecture](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/proposals/r1/Next-Consensus-Architecture-Proposal.md) with interest, and I have a question about the consensus service.  It seems to me that this is effectively a single service that guarantees all peers receive blocks in an order it decides.  As such it looks like it would have to be run by a single identified and trusted organization at any given time for a given chain.  It doesn't look like the service could be distributed.  Is that correct, or have I misunderstood?

This isn't really a programming question: if this is the wrong place to ask this question perhaps someone can let me know please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The Kafka Orderer is now production-ready:

> **Solo ordering service (testing):** The solo ordering service is intended to be an extremely easy to deploy, non-production ordering
>   service. It consists of a single process which serves all clients, so
>   consensus is not required as there is a single central authority.
>   There is correspondingly no high availability or scalability. This
>   makes solo ideal for development and testing, but not for deployment.
>
> **Kafka-based ordering service (production):** The Kafka-based ordering service leverages the Kafka pub/sub system to perform the
>   ordering, but wraps this in the familiar ab.proto definition so that
>   the peer orderer client code does not to be written specifically for
>   Kafka. Kafka is currently the preferred choice for production
>   deployments which demand high throughput and high availability, but do
>   not require byzantine fault tolerance.
>
> **PBFT ordering service (pending):** The PBFT ordering service will use the Hyperledger Fabric PBFT implementation (currently under
>   development) to order messages in a byzantine fault tolerant way.

---

Consensus service in Hyperledger Fabric is a pluggable module. There is [information](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/orderer/README.md) about 3 announced implementations:

> **Solo Orderer**:
>   The solo orderer is intended to be an extremely easy to deploy, non-production orderer. It consists of a single process which serves
>   all clients, so no `consensus' is required as there is a single
>   central authority. There is correspondingly no high availability or
>   scalability. This makes solo ideal for development and testing, but
>   not deployment. The Solo orderer depends on a backing raw ledger.
>
> **Kafka Orderer (pending)**:
>   The Kafka orderer leverages the Kafka pubsub system to perform the ordering, but wraps this in the familiar ab.proto definition so that
>   the peer orderer client code does not to be written specifically for
>   Kafka. In real world deployments, it would be expected that the Kafka
>   proto service would bound locally in process, as Kafka has its own
>   robust wire protocol. However, for testing or novel deployment
>   scenarios, the Kafka orderer may be deployed as a network service.
>   Kafka is anticipated to be the preferred choice production deployments
>   which demand high throughput and high availability but do not require
>   byzantine fault tolerance. The Kafka orderer does not utilize a
>   backing raw ledger because this is handled by the Kafka brokers.
>
> **PBFT Orderer (pending)**:
>   The PBFT orderer uses the hyperledger fabric PBFT implementation to order messages in a byzantine fault tolerant way. Because the
>   implementation is being developed expressly for the hyperledger
>   fabric, the ab.proto is used for wireline communication to the PBFT
>   orderer. Therefore it is unusual to bind the PBFT orderer into the
>   peer process, though might be desirable for some deployments. The PBFT
>   orderer depends on a backing raw ledger.

- For the Solo orderer (available now) the statement "have to be run by a single identified and trusted organization" is true.
- Kafka orderer (in development) - should  be possible to be deployed in distributed manner.
- PBFT Orderer - have found no information about this implementation.